# "Также": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

"Гарантирую качественное выполнение домашней работы, а так же подготовка к контрольным работам". Как в данном случае пишется "так же", разве не слитно?

Comment: На этом сайте нашла полный разбор моментов с слово "также" https://nauka.club/russkij-yazyk/takzhe-slitno-ili-razdelno.html

Answer (score 1):

**Гарантирую качественное выполнение домашней работы, а также подготовку к контрольным работам.**

**А ТАКЖЕ** ― присоединительный союз со слитным написанием частицы ЖЕ.

Сравнить:

Он так же хорошо подготовился к следующему экзамену (= как и к первому).

Он также  подготовился к следующему экзамену (= и к следующему экзамену тоже).

Comment: Обратите внимание, Arina исправила окончание в слове *подготовка*: гарантирую ... подготовкУ

Answer (score 1):

ТА́КЖЕ
*Вместе с тем, одновременно, равным образом, вдобавок* (выражает добавление).
Употребляется как присоединительный союз, обычно в сочетании с союзами "а", "и".
Присоединяет однородные члены предложения или предложения в составе сложного.

Правильно:
[Я] ***Гарантирую*** (что?) *качественное **выполнение** домашней работы, а также **подготовку*** (В. п.) *к контрольным работам* (однородные дополнения).
Или:
***Гарантируется*** качественное **выполнение** домашней работы, а также **подготовка** к контрольным работам (однородные подлежащие).

В любом случае "также" пишется слитно.